# Phalcon keeps using index.phtml for different Controllers

Tags: phalcon

I'm new to Phalcon and I like the framework but I have problems with links. I use phalcon version 0.6.1 and XAMPP 1.8.1 that has vhosts set to xampp/htdocs/test where my phalcon test is.

I have been following the tutorial and came to a problem. When I use links to load other controllers the adress bar shows the correct path but as far as I can see the index.phtml get loaded every time. I uploaded the files [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B49VRWgNhJMdWmxtV05YSXdEaE0) so you can see for yourselves.

It doesn't matter if I use Tag::LinkTo() or  since it doesn't change.

***edit:***

I followed the [instructions](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.7.0/reference/apache.html), removed the .htaccess files from the /test and /test/public directories to move the to httpd.conf. At the end of it I added

> ```
> <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/test">
>     RewriteEngine on
>     RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
>     RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/test/public">
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
> </Directory>
> ```

and modified my httpd-vhosts.conf like this

> ```
> ServerAdmin admin@example.host
> DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/public"
> DirectoryIndex index.php
> ServerName example.host
> ServerAlias www.example.host
>
> <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/public">
>     Options All
>     AllowOverride All
>     Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

The page loads but the absolute links like /public/css/bootstrap.min.css don't work and when I click the link it gives me an error 404 and says Object not found. I modified the files like this:

> ```
> <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/test">
>     RewriteEngine on
>     RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
>     RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/public">
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
> </Directory>
> ```

and

> ```
> ServerAdmin admin@example.host
> DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
> DirectoryIndex index.php
> ServerName example.host
> ServerAlias www.example.host
>
> <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/test">
>     Options All
>     AllowOverride All
>     Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

But that brings me to my original problem that when I click the link it loads index.phtml again even though it says localhost:8005/sample in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Apache configuration is not allowing reading the .htaccess file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName phalcon.test

    DocumentRoot /srv/htdocs/sites/test        

    <Directory "/srv/htdocs/sites/test">
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Also, at the top of your public/index.php check that $_GET['_url'] has the URI passed to your browser

Comment: The URI gets passed to the browser and I modified vhosts but it didn't still the same thing keeps hapenning. The adress bar shows localhost/sample but it loads index.phtml instead of sample.phtml.

Comment: I added a chapter to the framework documentation explaining how to install a Phalcon application in a Virtual Host: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.7.0/reference/apache.html, Hope that helps

Comment: I edited the question to reflect on the tutorial. Unfortunately I didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Is your VirtualHost listening on port 80?

Comment: I have multiple projects so I assigned port 8005 for this one.

Comment: I downloaded XAMPP 1.8.1, it comes with PHP 5.4.7, so I downloaded the DLL for PHP 5.4, then I followed these steps to make the VirtualHost work: https://gist.github.com/4156826

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it didn't change. I don't know what's wrong. Vhosts work as they did before but it just won't load other .phtml files. I downloaded INVO from github, installed it to localhost:8003 and it works without problems. I guess the problem is in the code but I can't find it since I followed the tutorial.

Comment: I see the problem, the views/index.phtml is the main view for your application, if you want to have a view per controller you need to move both index.phtml/sample.phtml to app/views/layouts